# Adding Additional information to dropdown box options

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am wanting to add hidden/additional information to a dropdown box. Currently, it works using

javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyText1 = document.getElementById("ID");
  

  var value = copyText1.value;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(value);

}
```

and html

```
<select id="ID">
     <option>Call James</option>
     <option>Call Bob</option>
     <option>Call Jane</option>
</select>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy number</button>
```

however, I would like when 'Call James' is selected, the copy number will copy a phone number (eg - '5551234') to the clipboard instead of the text 'Call James'

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Debugging and CSP wise: avoid using inline `on*` handlers. JS should be in one place only, and that's its respective tag or file

Answer (score 1):

- Use the Element's `value` attribute to store and then retrieve the *number*
- Stop using inline `on*` handlers. Use [Element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.
- Use `type="button"` since buttons are by default of type *Submit*.

```js
const elSelect = document.querySelector("#ID");
const elCopy = document.querySelector("#copy");

const copyNUmber = () => {
  console.log(elSelect.value);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(elSelect.value);
};

elCopy.addEventListener("click", copyNUmber);
```

```html
<select id="ID">
  <option value="123456000">Call James</option>
  <option value="654321000">Call Bob</option>
  <option value="999999000">Call Jane</option>
</select>

<button id="copy" type="button">Copy number</button>
```